# Layout inspector in android studio not finding my emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to use the layout inspector in my compose app, but anytime I run my app, I can't find my
emulator in the layout inspector available devices, but it finds my physical device... I am using AS Giraffe

I was expecting to find my emulator in running devices in my layout inspector

Answer (score 2):

You need to invalidate caches(When you invalidate the cache, Android Studio rebuilds all projects you had opened in the current version of the IDE) and restart your android studio.

`Go to:File-> Click:Invalidate caches...-> Check:1st and 2nd options-> Click:Invalidate and Restart`