# Function "setContent" keeps crashing my Andriod app

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am following the jetpack tutorial on google's site: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial
But when I try to run the code, the refuses to launch. I am using the latest version of android studio and API 34.

Here is my code:

```
package com.app1.app1

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.material3.Text

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
          setContent {
              MessageCard("Matt")
          }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MessageCard(name: String) {
    Text(text = "Hello $name!")
}
```

And these are the logs:

```
17:02:03.719  W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~GY4CdUSsI14breeI4KXVIg==/com.app1.app1-trtyu0tTL5-i-SDx3OR2cg==/base.dm': No such file or directory
17:02:03.719  W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~GY4CdUSsI14breeI4KXVIg==/com.app1.app1-trtyu0tTL5-i-SDx3OR2cg==/base.dm': No such file or directory
17:02:03.793  D  Configuring clns-4 for other apk /data/app/~~GY4CdUSsI14breeI4KXVIg==/com.app1.app1-trtyu0tTL5-i-SDx3OR2cg==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~GY4CdUSsI14breeI4KXVIg==/com.app1.app1-trtyu0tTL5-i-SDx3OR2cg==/lib/arm64, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.app1.app1
17:02:03.802  V  ANGLE Developer option for 'com.app1.app1' set to: 'default'
17:02:03.802  V  ANGLE GameManagerService for com.app1.app1: false
17:02:03.802  V  Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
17:02:03.805  D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
17:02:03.805  D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
17:02:03.832  D  Shutting down VM
17:02:03.835  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
             Process: com.app1.app1, PID: 16669
             java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setContent$default(Landroidx/activity/ComponentActivity;Landroidx/compose/runtime/
CompositionContext;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;ILjava/lang/Object;)V in class Landroidx/activity/compose/ComponentActivityKt; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.activity.compose.ComponentActivityKt' appears in /data/app/~~GY4CdUSsI14breeI4KXVIg==/com.app1.app1-trtyu0tTL5-i-SDx3OR2cg==/base.apk)
    at com.app1.app1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:13)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8342)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8321)               
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1417)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3625)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3781)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:138)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2306)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7918)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
----------------- PROCESS ENDED (16669) for package com.app1.app1 ---------------------
```

The issue seems to be the "setContent" function but I have no idea why. Do note that I am a beginner when it comes to developing android apps. If you need more info please don't hesitate to ask for it. Thanks!

Edited:
Also here is the build.gradle (module) file:

```
plugins {
     id("com.android.application")
     id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.app1.app1"
    compileSdk = 34

    buildFeatures {
    compose = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.app1.app1"
        minSdk = 29
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner = 
    "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android- 
            optimize.txt"),"proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0")
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")



implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4"
)
implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0- 
beta01")
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0- 
alpha09")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview- 
android:1.5.3")
testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.5.1")
}
```

And here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.APP1"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" 
                />

                <category 
                 android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: Do you have this dependency "androidx.activity:activity-compose" on your build.gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just verify and add the following line in the app Gradle file if not added automatically:

```
build.gradle(:app)
```

```
defaultConfig { 
    targetSdk = 34  // Update this
}

buildFeatures {
    compose true
}

composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.3"
}
```

Also verify below things:

```
build.gradle(APP1)
```

```
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.10" apply false
```

Comment: If this doesn't work then please share your app gradle code and manifest file

Comment: It didn't work, I am now getting this error: "Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.CompilationErrorException: Compilation error. See log for more details" I have added the files you requested, if you need any other please ask for it.

Comment: Here is what the compiler seas:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setContent$default(Landroidx/activity/ComponentActivity;Landroidx/compose/runtime/CompositionContext;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;ILjava/lang/Object;)V in class Landroidx/activity/compose/ComponentActivityKt; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.activity.compose.ComponentActivityKt' appears in /data/app/~~YuWk7rCMRHZgopHhitkl_g==/com.app1.app1-4nRIoQYDp31ZxRMkyPhM5g==/base.apk)

Comment: Please try updated answer

Comment: Also Clean Project and then follow this steps to invalidate caches: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76950270/19212377

Comment: Now it works, thanks so much. Also sorry for answering so late.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the dependency for `activity-compose` exists in your `build.gradle` file (not the project one, but the module one. It is typically within the `app` folder).

The dependency looks like this:

`implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")`

If the dependency isn't there within the `dependencies` block, then add it yourself as a line there. Your `build.gradle` bottom lines will look like this:

```
dependencies {

    //...other dependencies...
    //...

    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
}
```

Make sure that the dependency is `implementation` and not `runtimeOnly` or `compileOnly`

Comment: It wasn't, so I added it, but it still crashes. Any other ideas?

Comment: @R1B07008 I suggest you clean the project + invalidate caches, then see what's up. Try also changing the `activity-compose` dependency version back to 1.7.2, there might be a regression issue. Last but not least, test on another phone.